# Compare list w/ sublist

Tags: python

I have 2 lists:

```
lista = ['1.2.3.4', '2.3.4.5', '3.4.5.6'] # 12,000 IP's
listb = [['1.2.3.4', 'info', 'moreinfo', 'moremoreinfo'], ['2.3.4.5', 'info', 'moreinfo', 'moremoreinfo']] # 1.8m IP's + info
```

I'm looking for a way to take lista, if the ip exsits in listb, give me all the info on it.

I've tried looping, but its incredibly slow:

```
for listaitem in lista:
    for listbitem in listb:
        if listaitem in listbitem[0]:
            print listbitem
```

Any suggetions on how to speed this up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could turn `lista` into a set for fast membership testing, then just loop over `listb` to select any that are found in `lista`:

```
lista_set = set(lista)
for item in listb:
    if item[0] in lista_set:
        print item
```

The next step is turning `listb` into a dictionary:

```
listb_dict = {item[0]: item[1:] for item in listb}
```

Now you can use sets to pick out *just* the ones that are both in `lista_set` and `listb_dict`:

```
for match in listb_dict.viewkeys() & lista_set:
    print match, listb_dict[match]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lista = ['1.2.3.4', '2.3.4.5', '3.4.5.6']
listb = [['1.2.3.4', 'info', 'moreinfo', 'moremoreinfo'],
         ['2.3.4.5', 'info', 'moreinfo', 'moremoreinfo']]
```

Turn `listb` into a dictionary

```
dictb = {i[0] : i[1:] for i in listb}
```

Iterate over `lista` and look for entries in `dictb`

```
for elem in lista:
    print dictb.get(elem)

['info', 'moreinfo', 'moremoreinfo']
['info', 'moreinfo', 'moremoreinfo']
None
```

Answer (score 1):

You should convert the data to a format more suitable for searching: a dictionary.

```
ip_info = {info[0]: info[1:] for info in listb}
```

Then you can very quickly look up information about a particular IP.

```
for ip in lista:
    if ip in ip_info:
        print(ip_info[ip])
```